# How to select a textbox using Python Selenium when id changes and there are no labels

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select this element

```
<textarea cdktextareaautosize="" class="cdk-textarea-autosize mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" matinput="" rows="1" placeholder="" maxlength="4000" id="mat-input-54" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false" style="height: 954px;"></textarea>
```

The id changes every time the page reloads.  What can I do?

Comment: Post some of the surrounding HTML... look for some elements up the DOM that contain an ID or other unique identifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the element, I'd first try a CSS selector. CSS selectors are pretty powerful and can even get elements by partial IDs. Try this:

```py
browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.cdk-textarea-autosize.mat-input-element.mat-form-field-autofill-control.cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored[id^="mat-input-"][rows="1"][maxlength="4000"]')
```

I'll break down the selector:

- `.cdk-textarea-autosize.mat-input-element.mat-form-field-autofill-control.cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored` matches all the classes that are on the element, except the ones that start with `ng-`, as those are used by Angular and could change at any time.
- `[id^="mat-input-"]` matches an ID that starts with `mat-input`, but says nothing about the number
- `[rows="1"][maxlength="4000"]` matches the `row` and `maxlength` attributes of the element

Comment: The element after I detach the sidebar is

<textarea cdktextareaautosize="" class="cdk-textarea-autosize mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty" matinput="" rows="1" placeholder="" maxlength="4000" id="mat-input-54" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false" style="height: 18px;"></textarea>

Comment: @MichaelCovell Sorry for the late response because of Easter. It looks like the site uses Angular and is removing the classes that start with `ng-`. I modified my answer to work with this. Can you try it again now with the updated code?

Comment: Also, if my updated answer solves your issue, then you can mark it as correct to help guide others with the same issue in the future.